# Create custom operator c++

Tags: c++, operators

I'd like to ask is possible define custom operator in C++ ex.:

```
Func function;
double a[2] = {-3, 3};
function = function integrate a;
```

Note: integrate is operator for numeric integration over interval <-3, 3>.

I'm really interested only how I can create my own operator.

Thank you for yours responses and time.
Mari

Comment: The language does not allow you to introduce new operator symbols, and using one of the existing ones to do something different could be confusing (but it has been done.)

Comment: You could search for Yakk's named operator approach. It looks like this: `function <integrate> a`, or similarly `function *integrate* a`. But IMHO, `integrate(function, a)` doesn't look bad either.

Comment: I've found on net that is possible. But I don't know how.

For example, I've found library [link](http://cogwheel.info/idop/). But I don't understand principle of creating custom operators.

Comment: @user47779: It appears to be using Yakk's named operators, hidden behind a macro

Comment: @MooingDuck Yakk's named operators? Do you have any link for this?

Comment: @user47779: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=100233

Comment: @user47779, FWIW, there's a git repo based on that: https://github.com/klmr/named-operator

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just write a class for your integration method (maybe a complete class hierachy)  or a function is also sufficient. Then give it the function you want to integrate as a parameter (using [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/) will allow this to be a function pointer, functor or lambda expression) and the range of your integration. This is the way I did this recently. For example in 1D:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

double integrate(std::function<double(double)> f, double a, double b)
{
    return (b-a)/2.0*(f(a)+f(b));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << integrate([](double x){ return x*x;}, -3.0, 3.0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an itegration operator. You can create a function to integrate

```
#include <functional>
typedef std::function<double(double)> Function;

double integrate(Function func, double a[])
{
    double result = 0.0;
    //do numeric integration
    return result;
}
double my_func(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}
int main()
{
    double a[] = {-3.0, 3.0};
    const double result = integrate(my_func, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not define custom operators.
You can only change the meaning of existing ones.
But precedence and grouping are preserved as they were for the original operators.

Comment: What you should NEVER do is use the macro preprocessor to define integrate as * and then overload that... ;=)

Comment: Note that if you overload any of the boolean operators you lose short-circuit evaluation.