# Is it possible to use an arbitrary character as an operator?

Tags: c++, operators

**As a prior note:** This is not something I would 'desire' to achieve; more-so a question related to if it's actually possible.

**N.B.** I understand (and have used) Operator Overloding in C++. For example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj){ return os; }
```

---

Is it possible to define a custom ASCII character to act as an operator?

For example, in a simple sense: use the *grave accent* (`) as an 'alias' for std::pow.

Whereby, the following statement would be valid/achievable:

```
std::cout << 2`3 << std::endl;

>> 8
```

Comment: No. You can overload existing ones to do what you want, you could even fiddle with macros so the preprocessor replaces that accent with another operator. Whether that is a good idea is another thing though..

Comment: Custom build of g++ ;-)

Comment: You could supply an operator for a [*user-defined literal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#User-defined_literals) suffix, such that e.g. 2.3_pow meant 2^3  - you'd need to use the variadic template model, forming an instantiation ala `< '2', '.', '3' >`, or settle for "2.3"_pow and handle a `const char*` at runtime.  It'd be tedious to write the operator template and ugly (even misleading given 2.3 looks like a float/double) in usage anyway....

Comment: @TonyD An alternative would be `2_pow ->* 3` with an overloaded `->*` to mean "apply to."

Comment: @Angew: could do that... or just `2_n ^ 3` (on [ideone](http://ideone.com/icodHV)), though there's a solid argument that's more confusing for hijacking bitwise-OR.

Comment: @TonyD I used `->*` because of its high precedence. You could take any operator with a suitable one.

Comment: You are certainly aware that the _"S"_ in "ASCII" stands for _"standard"_? And that therefore _"custom ASCII character"_ is a contradiction in terms? (Just kidding.)

Comment: FYI Haskell has the feature you want; a web search for "infix operators in Haskell" should yield interesting reading.

Comment: @EricLippert why Haskell in particular? Lots of languages have infix operators - for example swift and scala.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Because Haskell is awesome?  As is Scala of course. Swift I have insufficient data upon which to make a judgment.

Comment: Related questions (I previously listed these in meta discussion about this Q): Or not. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25513374/103167 http://stackoverflow.com/q/15090209/103167 http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/23179/2150 http://stackoverflow.com/q/20861231/103167 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14782169/103167

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You cannot introduce a character not present in the syntax, such as the backtick you mentioned. But there is a ["named operator" trick](https://github.com/klmr/named-operator) with which you can introduce a "named operator" to achieve the following syntax:

```
std::cout << (2 <Pow> 3) << std::endl;
```

The trick relies on overloading `<` and `>` for a custom type, like this:

```
const struct PowOperator {} Pow;

struct PowInvoker
{
  int lhs;
};

PowInvoker operator< (int lhs, PowOperator)
{
  return {lhs};
}

int operator> (PowInvoker lhs, int rhs)
{
  return std::pow(lhs.lhs, rhs);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << (2 <Pow> 3) << std::endl;
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b0ce49e0e6c2cb4)

Notice that you cannot affect the precedence of these named operators: they will have the same precedence as `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`. If you need different precedence, you'd have to use a different delimiter (which would probably not be as nicely readable).

---

**Disclaimer**

The above trick is "clever" code, it's pretty much an abuse of the C++ syntax. I took the question as a hypothetical "what is possible," and answered with an equally hypothetical "this is." I would *not* recommend using this in practice for such trivial matters as replacing `std::pow` or providing "novelty" syntax for the sake of it. The operator precedence caveat mentioned above is one reason; general unfamiliarity of the construct is another. Code quality is measured in the number of WTFs the code generates (fewer is better), and this trick generates a whole bunch of them (and big ones at that).

It still has its uses: for creating a Domain-Specific Language. There are cases in programming where embedding a DSL into C++ code is in order; in such cases (and *only* in such cases) would I consider using this.

Comment: I'd savagely mutilate anyone who used that in "real" code, but +1 for an interesting answer to a hypothetical question.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Replacing `std::pow` is not what this is for, but it can provide a viable DSL for some situations.

Comment: @Angew Interesting concept; thank you for the link to the 'named-operator' trick. I've never actually seen this done before.

Comment: AFAICT -and it might be worth mentioning in your answer- it seems that you are still limited to using a valid idenitifier name for the name of your operator... does C++ allow for Unicode characters in legal identifiers?

Comment: @ArtB: I think that's compiler specific.  C++ disallows a couple characters, requires a few, but all the rest are up to the compiler.

Comment: Also it occurs to me that one could use a macro `#define POW ->*Pow->*` which would be closer to what the OP asked for, and binds tighter.

Comment: @Angew I was wondering, is this (in a broad sense of the word) guaranteed to work? I.e., could something like operator precedence 'break' the code?

Comment: @sanchises Yes, operator precedence can indeed break it. Notice I (had to) put parentheses around the subexpression in the output statement. Named operators constructed in this way will always have the same precedence as `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`. As Mooing Duck mentioned, you could use a different operator for delimiter to achieve more favourable binding (such as `->*`, the tightest-binding general-purpose infix operator).

Comment: This hack deserves a "C++ Arcana Of The Year" award.

Answer (score 11):

No, that is not possible. Even at the preprocessor level you are limited by the characters that form valid preprocessor tokens and macro names, and then the language grammar fixes the set of operators in the language.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Kerrek. I was convinced that it wasn't possible; just hadn't seen adequate information about the topic on the web. Thanks for clearing that up. :-)